# DISPLAY DATA FROM TWO SEPERATE TABLE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to DISPLAY all customer name and their phone no under the Agent named Santakumar which have AGENT_CODE = A010.

the customers data have different table and agents data have also in the different table. the only thing that connect to them is AGENT_CODE.

I try using this QUERY but nothing happens and give this error:
Error Code: 1052. Column 'AGENT_CODE' in where clause is ambiguous  0.000 sec

```
SELECT A.AGENT_NAME, C.CUST_NAME, C.PHONE_NO
FROM agents AS A
JOIN customer AS C ON A.AGENT_CODE = C.AGENT_CODE
WHERE AGENT_CODE = 'A010'
```

Im new to MYSql so im not really that skilled in this field.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since AGENT_CODE exists in more than one table/alias, you have to specify to which one you are referring to in the where clause:

```
WHERE A.AGENT_CODE = 'A010'
```